# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to select one row when I click a button, but it get an error.

This website used to be work fine.

```
 protected void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
        int index = gvRow.RowIndex;

         string rute  = gridview_busqueda.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text; <-- 
          string rute1 = gridview_busqueda.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;
          string rute2 = gridview_busqueda.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text;
          string rute3 = gridview_busqueda.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text;
          string rute4 = gridview_busqueda.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text;
      }

<asp:GridView ID="gridview_busqueda" Width="100%" 
      name="gridview_busqueda" EmptyDataText="No hay valores para Mostrar." 
      runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeaderStyle-BackColor = "#e6e6e6"
      AllowPaging ="true" OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging">
    <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Nombre"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Rut" HeaderText="Rut" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Gerencia" HeaderText="Gerencia"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Cargo" HeaderText="Cargo"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Vigencia_desde" HeaderText="Vigencia_desde"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Vigencia_hasta" HeaderText="Vigencia_hasta"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fecha_creacion" HeaderText="Fecha Creacion"   />

    <%-- Adding button to gridview --%>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Btn1" runat="server" 
             Text="Ver Mas" CommandArgument="Button1"
             OnClick="Btn1_Click" />
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>         
   </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Error:

```
'gridview_busqueda.Rows[index]' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}
```

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Why not just `gvRow.Cells[0]...`?

Comment: the gridview is empty.. strange situation, due to in the web page shows 20 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the [index]. As you want to select values of particular row you can do the following.

```
protected void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    string rute = gvRow.Cells[0].Text;
    string rute1 = gvRow.Cells[1].Text;
    string rute2 = gvRow.Cells[2].Text;
    string rute3 = gvRow.Cells[3].Text;
    string rute4 = gvRow.Cells[4].Text;
}
```

Hope it works for you.